# Using extended tweets with Twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

There is this article https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets

where it is mentioned that

> The REST API endpoints that create new Tweets (statuses/update) will
>   accept a new boolean parameter when a Tweet is sent as a reply to a
>   conversation: auto_populate_reply_metadata (true to enable, false to
>   disable, false being the default). The existing in_reply_to_status_id
>   must also be set.

How can I use this parameter `auto_populate_reply_metadata` in the Twitter4j library? I did not find this parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a new feature, and already has a [pull request on the Twitter4j Library](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/pull/261). If you really needed right now you must made the [modifications by yourself](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/pull/261/files), or just wait to the library to be updated.